# Reagent - methods of storing ui state together with (or separate from?) server-persisted state?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm using multiple atoms within a map called app-state and it's working quite well architecturally so far. The state distributed across those atoms is normalised, reflecting as it is stored in datomic, and of course what the client is initialised with is a specific subset of what's in datomic. This is me preparing the way to try out datascript (which is what gave me the aha moment of why client state is so much better fully normalised, even if not using datascript).

I have a question at this point. We all know that some state in reagent is a reflection of what's in the server's database (typically), but there's also state in reagent concerning solely the current condition of the ui. That state will vanish when the page is re-loaded and there's (typically) no need to store that on the server.

So, I'm looking at my list of atoms and realising that I have some atoms which hold database-record-like maps, i.e. they contain exact reflections of datomic entities, (which arrive by transit), which is great.

But now I notice I also want some ui state **per datomic entity**.
So the question arises whether to (this seems wrong to me) add some keys to what came from datomic, of the ui state that is irrelevant to datomic, but that the client needs (i.e., dump it into the same nested map).  That is entirely possible, but seems wrong, and so suggests....   (this being my idea as of now), *How about a parallel atom per "entity"*, like `@<entity-name>-ui`, containing a map (or even a vector of maps, if multiple entities), with a set of keys for ui state.

That seems an improvement on what I have ended up with by default as of now, which is separate atom for every piece of ui state (I've avoided component local state up to now). (Currently the ui only holds ui state for one record at a time, so these ui atoms need only be concerned with a single current entity).

But if, say, I made a parallel atom (to avoid mixing ephemeral ui and server state), then ui state could perhaps manageably extend deeper. We could hold, say, ui state per entity so switching current-entity back and forth would remember ui state.

Since this is Stack Overflow, I have to ask a specific question, rather than this just be discussion, so: given what I've described, what are some sensible architectural choices in this case, to store state in reagent?

Comment: This is pretty open ended. For topics like this that are more of a discussion I'd suggest the clojure reddit (reddit.com/r/clojure) or clojurians slack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing your app state in several component-independent reagent atoms already - you can check https://github.com/day8/re-frame which is a widely-adopted reagent-powered framework exactly for your case. Essentially it stores all the application state in a reagent atom but has a well-developed infrastructure to support coordinated storage and updates. They have brilliant [documentation](https://day8.github.io/re-frame/re-frame/) with a great high-level explanation of the idea.
Regarding your initial question about server/ui state separation - I think you should definitely go this way. It'll give you a better way of separating concerns and give you an easier way to update server/ui data separately. It is very easy to achieve this with `re-frame` by storing both parts of the state under separate top-level keys in re-frame application db. E.g.

```
{:server {:entity-name ...} 
 :ui     {:entity-name ...}}
```

and then create suitable subscriptions(see re-frame docs) to retrieve it.